# Is there any way to stop Media Encoder creating this launch preventing file?

Tags: adobe, adobe-media-encoder

Media Encoder seems to bug out create this file which stops it launching.

[image]

I have to either have to manually delete it or launch this BAT file every time I want to launch the program.

[image]

Is there any way I can stop encoder from creating this file or does adobe have to fix the launch error?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution presented at https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1268390:

> Open the file (C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Adobe\SLCache\X19zbGNfZmVhdHVyZXNfXw==.slc) in any text editor,
>   delete all of the contents, save it, and set the file to read-only.